# Passing large Json data from C#(Web API) to Client(Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json

Is there any approach to pass large Json data from server side to client side and vice versa?

Now I am passing it by saving the Json data in file(.txt) and reading it in client as well as server side. But this approach is also taking large amount of time to write and read on it.

Please suggest some good practices.

Comment: Please quantify "large".  Also, what are you trying to do with the data ... is it being put on scope and bound or something else?

Comment: You can send/receive json directly with both web api and angular, no need to do anything crazy

Comment: File size comes around  minimum 5MB. I am downloading e-mails from various sites(Gmail, yahoo etc) and showing it to the user.